# get data attribute from link inside a ul list

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to grab a data attribute from a link inside a list, when I click on it.

```
$(document).on('click', "ul.pagination li a", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr("page");
    var article_id = getUrlParameter('aid');
    alert(page);
    $('.comments').load('page', {'type':'reload', 'article_id':article_id, 'page':page}, function() {
        $('.comments').scrollMinimal();
        $('.comments').highlight();
    });
});
```

A list would look like this:

```
<div class="fnone">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a data-page="2" href="testpage=2#comments">2</a></li>
```

My issue, is that "page" is always `undefined`. Not entirely sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: use `$(this).attr("data-page");`

Comment: document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.attr("data-page")` since that is the name of attribute

```js
$(document).on('click', "ul.pagination li a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
   alert(page)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A list would look like this:

<div class="fnone">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a data-page="2" href="testpage=2#comments">2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Doh, simple mistakes eh? Thank you :)